# AWS EC2 : Connecting to PostgreSQL from tomcat 7

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tomcat7, postgresql-9.2

I have installed tomcat7 and postgreSQL9 on AWS- Ec2 Micro ,
I am able to connect to the EC2 postgreSQL instance form a spring application running on my local tomcat 7 server.

When I deploy the same war file on the EC2- tomcat7 server, it is throwing the following error..

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgresql://ec2-user@x-x-x-x-x.us-x-x.compute.amazonaws.com/test'
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:279)
```

I have copied postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc3.jar to /usr/share/tomcat7/lib

I have tried using the AWS internal IP ... No luck..

I don't know what I am doing wrong. The same war with same configuration works from local tomcat7. Am I missing any thing with AWS tomcat7 configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Hi it seems you haven't included the postgresql jdbc jar. Try including that it should work.